# Disabling click event for a view but not for its childs

Tags: android, view, click, subview, touch-event

I have a `ListView` that its items have some buttons as child/sub view (buttons like share, reply, like, etc). I want to disable clicks on items but not for childs. For example when clicking on a like button, its color changes and nothing happens to the list view item. (see nine gag app)

I read similar questions saying about overriding `areAllItemsEnabled` and `isEnabled` and I did that (returning false for both) but didn't get proper result (childs also are unabled)

Can you please help me out? And sorry for my bad English

in custom adapter:

```
public CustomCommentAdaptor(Context context){ 
ctx = context;
listData = new ArrayList();
}
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

listview in main layout xml file

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:layout_above="@+id/leave_comment" />
```

and listview items layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <!-- android:padding="10dip" --> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@+drawable/brad" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_image"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_image"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RatingBar 
            style="@style/myRatingBar"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="5"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/comment_title"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comment_header"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/comment_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/comment_actions" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/dislike"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/comment_actions"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/reply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/comment_actions" 
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/comment_actions" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share some code what have you tried??

Comment: @altaf I have put some code. hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a click listener *only* on your buttons.  So, in your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    View likeView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    likeView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // Do something.

        }
    }
}
```

*Don't* set a click listener on your list.  So, if you are doing this anywhere, take it out!

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() ...);
```

Finally, to make the like button change colors when pressed, set a selector as the background of your `comment_actions` layout.